# Jsp fn length returns collection size 0

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

I am trying to count the number of elements in list provided from the controller
here is my js code

```
            var fingerListvar = "${fingerList}";
            console.log(fingerListvar);
            console.log(fingerListvar.length);
            var fingerCount = ${fn:length(fingerListvar)};
            console.log(fingerCount);
```

But in console i get the following output

```
//1st
[first, second, third]

//2nd
22

//3rd
0
```

If i remove double quote -

```
var fingerListvar = ${fingerList};
```

i get the following error

```
first is not defined ReferenceError: first is not defined
```

Comment: `fingerList` is a string. It appears you expect it to be an array. As such you can remove the `[]` characters and `split()` it, like this: `'[first, second, third]'.replace(/\[\]/g, '').split(', ')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But i can perform <c:forEach on  fingerList,